# Notifications trait in Sails.js - similar to Laravel?

Tags: sails.js

I'm coming from Laravel, moving to Sails.js, I was wondering how to handle notifications? Laravel has this - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications

A notifiable trait which we can add to the model. And then do `Model->notify(NotificationClass)`.

I went through the Sails 1.0 docs but can't find anything on notifications. Is there some information on this?

Comment: I think you need to implement manually in sails js.

Comment: Thanks Devsi yes I added it manually.